# Add custom file upload field on magento 2 checkout page

Tags: magento2.3

Does anybody know how to add file upload field on magento 2 checkout page after shipping information

Answer (score -1):

Here is the github module. You can use on Checkout Page.

**Add a custom form to Magento 2 checkout : https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form**

Comment: This module does not seem to provide a file upload field.

Comment: You have to use file upload code not text field.

Comment: Yes, and then you'd also have to provide facilities for the actual uploading. So I don't think this module solves the OPs requirements.

Comment: Okay I'll update. Thanks.